# JQuery Hide Option doesn't work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I use this code to hide option in IE and its work fine in all browser except IE 11
here are code to hide and show option

```
$("[id*=dllStates] option").each(function (index, val) {
            if ($(this).is('option') && (!$(this).parent().is('span')))
                $(this).wrap((navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') ? '<span>' : null).hide();
        });
```

and to show I use this

```
var counterIE = 0;
            $("[id*=dllStates]").next().children().html("Select Supplier");
            for (i = 0; i < supplierID.length; i++) {
                $("[id*=dllStates] option").each(function (index, val) {
                    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
                        if (this.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'OPTION') {
                            var span = $(this).parent();
                            var opt = this;
                            if ($(this).val() == supplierID[counterIE]) {
                                if ($(this).parent().is('span')) {
                                    $(opt).show();
                                    $(span).replaceWith(opt);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                counterIE = counterIE + 1;
            }
```

why this is not working in IE 11 Thanks

Comment: I don't know about IE11, but in older versions of IE you couldn't hide option elements, you had to remove them (or `.detach()` them) and then add them back when needed. I take it your `.wrap('span')` thing is a workaround to allow the hide to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE11, `navigator.appName` is not `'Microsoft Internet Explorer'`, it's actually `'Netscape'`.

Comment: if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' || navigator.appName == 'Netscape')  Is It Working ?

Comment: If you really feel you must test which browser is running you can't do it with `navigator.appName` because it will be `'Netscape'` in most modern browsers.